# How can I prevent js file download and return transfer into c# webBrowser?

Tags: javascript, .net, webbrowser-control

I have a script in php for changing ip on my huawei modem. I'm trying to do similar with c# webBrowser.

When I login into modem with c#, it throws a js file which is dynamically created (not a static file) and containing some variables.

Php curl automatical catches the file and returns it. So I can read and post those variables later.

But c# webbrowser returns a file download dialog and my script can't read those variables. How can I do this?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.1/api/system/user_login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

This is php way of doing it. And I can read the file with

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But c# form with webBrowser asks me to download a file named "user_login817dc01f.js" (file name and contents are changing everytime). Content is like this:

```
while(1); /*{"csrf_param":"W4A1th4QkgshQIJMzK7f0mg0rpzMd8m","csrf_token":"iR00ua1IVxD4jsVFmWSYttBYpP346Rn","Cat":"ok","level":2,"IsWizard":true,"IsFirst":true}*/
```

[image: huawei login file]

Those lines means I'm in router successfully. But my c# script needs to read those strings so I can create variables with them and do a final https post for restarting pppoe.

How can I prevent js file download and return transfer into c# webBrowser so I could get page contents with "webBrowser1.DocumentText" property?

Comment: Are you allowed to add Javascript on this page that returns the CSRF? I can easily provide a solution if this is the case.

Comment: @Raymond I don't know. It is router interface. 192.168.1.1

Comment: The page your logging into it is a web page right.

Comment: @Raymond yes. It is a webpage. Vdsl modem router login page. Full of javascript.

Comment: Can you post your solution @Raymond ?

Answer (score 1):

There might be an option for webBrowser to just show the text instead of downloading it.